# sqlite3: get column data types on table join

Tags: python, sqlite

Using sqlite3 in Python, I'd like to return the data types for all columns that result from a table 'JOIN'. This works fine,

```
SELECT typeof(t1.foo), typeof(t2.bar)  
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
```

unless a value is null. I'd like something equivalent to the PostgreSQL `pg_typeof()` function where I can get the declared data type (such as from a `PRAGMA` statement) for each column from an arbitrary SQL query that contains a `JOIN`.

Thanks!

Comment: In SQLite, column types [do not matter much](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so Python has no function to access them.